# Using JGit to list all revisions to a repository

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am trying to use JGit to go through a repository, and for each pair of parent/child commits I want to somehow get the difference between them, or the revision made from one to the other. I don't know much about Git or JGit, so this is probably an easy task but I am still stumped.

Would using a RevWalk be a valid way of getting parent/child commits? I saw that in a lot of code snippets from the JGit documentation. I have no clue where to begin about taking the difference between them once I have them, though.

Answer (score 0):

It think this [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/WalkAllCommits.java) from the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) may be a good starting point. It shows how you can walk across all commits of a local repository.

```
        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
            int count = 0;
            for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
                System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
```

If you rather look for information from a remote repository, there is a way to at least iterate commits on a remote repository, see [this snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemotes.java)